How to adjust the mediums priority for Android Nearby Share?
I am trying to use nearby to send file to others. There are so many mediums to send to peer. WIFI_DIRECT, WIFI_HOTSPOT, WIFI_AWARE.  like below log
10-10 20:20:44.789590  2149  6807 I NearbyConnections: Computed the intersection of supported mediums with endpoint XBC4. Between their supported mediums ([WIFI_AWARE, WIFI_DIRECT, WIFI_HOTSPOT, BLE_L2CAP, BLUETOOTH, BLE]) and my supported mediums ([WIFI_LAN, WIFI_DIRECT, WIFI_AWARE, WIFI_HOTSPOT, WEB_RTC, BLE_L2CAP, BLUETOOTH, BLE]) we decided on the combined subset ([WIFI_AWARE, WIFI_DIRECT, WIFI_HOTSPOT, BLE_L2CAP, BLUETOOTH, BLE]).
i.e. changing from
[WIFI_LAN, WIFI_DIRECT, WIFI_AWARE, WIFI_HOTSPOT, WEB_RTC, BLE_L2CAP, BLUETOOTH, BLE]
to
[WIFI_HOTSPOT, WIFI_LAN, WIFI_DIRECT, WIFI_AWARE, WEB_RTC, BLE_L2CAP, BLUETOOTH, BLE]
and make it to use WIFI_HOTSPOT as connection
Is there any way to adjust the priority WIFI_HOTSPOT in front of WIFI_AWARE?
I would like to test all the WIFI option to make sure it work well for all combination
looks like somehow there is some settings in com.google.android.gms/databases/phenotype.dbcom.google.android.gms/databases/phenotype.db
However, I don't know which one can be using it for mediums priority
